# jquery append to DOM does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a simple question. I have this function:

```
    function buildGallery(assets) {
        var $target = $("#assets");
        var containerWidth = $target.width();
        var overallWidth = 0;
        var items = "";

        $.each(assets, function (i, asset) {
            var percent = 300 / asset.Metadata.ImageHeight;
            var width = percent * asset.Metadata.ImageWidth;
            var item = "<img src=\"" + asset.ThumbNail + "\" />";

            overallWidth += width;
            items += item;

            if (overallWidth >= containerWidth) {
                var $items = $(items);
                var padding = overallWidth - containerWidth;
                var counter = $items.find("img").length;
                var p = padding / counter;

                $items.each(function (n, image) {
                    console.log(image);

                    var img = "<div style=\"float: left; width: " + p + "px; overflow: auto;\">" + image + "</div>";

                    $target.append(img);
                });

                overallWidth = 0; // reset
                items = "";
            }
        });

        $target.removeClass("ajax");
    }
```

my problem is that when I try to add the div to my target it just shows [object HTMLDivElement] instead of actually showing the html.

I have seen this before, but whatever I try does not seem to work. 
Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(image);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to build the new div element with the image DOM element, rather than its HTML:

```
var img = "<div style=\"float: left; width: " + p + "px; overflow: auto;\">" + image + "</div>";
                                           // this is a DOM object not a string ^
```

If you want to use the string form, you need to get the HTML string from the object:

```
var img = "<div style=\"float: left; width: " + p + "px; overflow: auto;\">" + image.innerHTML + "</div>";
```

Or you could create a jQuery object of the div and append the image element to it:

```
var img = $("<div style=\"float: left; width: " + p + "px; overflow: auto;\"></div>").append(image);
```

Though it might be easier to read if you wrap each of the images in a div in one step and then add all of them to the `$target` at once:

```
$items.wrap("<div style=\"float: left; width: " + p + "px; overflow: auto;\"></div>").appendTo($target);
```

I think that you might have another problem with your code: it looks like the `if (overallWidth >= containerWidth) {` statement should be *outside* of the `$.each(assets, ...)` loop. With it inside, you will be adding each element in the assets list to the DOM `length - index` times.